# How to pass one or more field value to another field custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have search on Internet, how to pass one field value to another field custom directive. But i did not get success. Here is the code:

```
module.directive("confirmPassword", function(){
    return {        
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {
          cpassword: '=confirmPassword'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,ctrl){ 
          if(!ctrl) return;

          console.log(scope.cpassword);
          ctrl.$validators.confirmPasswd = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            var value = modelValue || viewValue;
            console.log(attrs.confirmPassword);
            console.log(value);
              if(angular.isDefined(value)){
                  if(scope.cpassword.test(value)) {
                      scope.confirmStrength = 'valid';
                      ctrl.$setValidity("confirmInvalid",true);
                      return true;
                  } else {
                      scope.confirmStrength = 'invalid';
                      ctrl.$setValidity("confirmInvalid",false);
                      return false;
                  }
              }
              return false;
          }
        }
    };
});
```

and in i am applying this custom directive to the field like:

```
<input type="password" confirm-password="registerData.password" ng-model="registerData.confirmPassword">
```

but i am not getting desire output. something i am missing in this. Please help me somebody. I am using angularJs 1.4 version.

Please find [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MXTPqXMUWIQVIdS7sbyF?p=preview)

Comment: You use isolated scope and define cpassword variable. You should try do: <input type="password" confirm-password  cpassword="registerData.password" ... />

Comment: Ok, I'll try this one.

Comment: that's is not working.

Comment: could you make a fidlle or plunker ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crkqhdcb/ it works. Anyway you have ctrl required.

Comment: console.log(scope.cpassword); didn't log anything in your directive ??

Comment: console.log(scope.cpassword); says undefined.

Comment: Are you sure that you have registerData.password in your scope? you bind registerData.confirmPassword.

Comment: I have two fields. one is for password and second is for confirm password. Please see plunker  i have added. I am getting error on test() function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for every for there efforts. I have found the solution. One of my directive creating problem due to that value not passed to confirm password directive.